# Algorithm Complexity: Is it the same to iterate an array from the start than from the end?

Tags: java, algorithm

In an interview I was asked for the following:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int [] array = new int [10000];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       // do calculations   
    }

    for (int x = array.length-1; x >= 0; x--) {
       // do calculations   
    }


}
```

}

Is it the same to iterate an array either from the end or from the start? As my understanding it would be the same since complexity is constant i.e O(1) ? Am I correct?

Also I was asked regarding ArrayList Complexity compared to other collections in java, for example, LinkedList.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the difference between the *start* **and** the *beginning*?

Comment: If the _do calculations_ part is O(1) then the complexity is obviously O(_n_), _n_ being the number of elements in the array. Access to _one_ array element takes constant time, O(1), and you have _n_ of them.

Comment: If you have to iterate over the entire list it does not matter. If in your calculation you have a good chance of going out (via a break) you have to choose the most likely solution.

Comment: CPU prefetching characteristics can make a difference.

Comment: `array.length` is called 10000 times for the first example, and once for the second, at least in theory. It will probably be optimized anyway.

Answer (score 5):

There can be a difference due to CPU prefetch characteristics.

There is no difference between looping in either direction as per computational theory. However, depending on the kind of prefetcher that is used by the CPU on which the code runs, there will be some differences in practice.

For example, the Sandy Bridge Intel processor has a prefetcher that goes forward only for data (while instructions could be prefetched in both directions). This will help iteration from the start (as future memory locations are prefetched into the L1 cache), while iterating from the end will cause very little to no prefetching, and hence more accesses to RAM which is much slower than accessing any of the CPU caches.

There is a more detailed discussion about forward and backward prefetching at this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mechanical-sympathy/3t7W5GCZ2ss).

Answer (score 1):

It's O(n) in both cases for an array, as there are n iterations and each step takes O(1) (assuming the calculations in the loop take O(1)). In particular, obtaining the length or size is typically an O(1) operation for arrays or ArrayList.

A typical use case for iterating from the end is removing elements in the loop (which may otherwise require more complex accounting to avoid skipping elements or iterating beyond the end).

For a linked list, the first loop would typically be O(n²), as determining the length of a linked list is typically an O(n) operation without additional caching, and it's used every time the exit condition is checked. **However**, java.util.LinkedList keeps explicitly track of the length, so the total is O(n) for linked lists in java.

If an element in a linked list is accessed using the index in the calculations, this will be an O(n) operation, yielding  a total of O(n²).

Comment: Obtaining the size of a LinkedList is O(1). The list has a field to keep its size. It doesn't iterate to know it. Doing list.get(i), however, is very costly in a LinkedList, since it needs to iterate. That's why an Iterator should be used to traverse a list, instead of accessing the elements by their index.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it the same to iterate an array either from the end or from the start? As my understanding it would be the same since complexity is constant i.e O(1) ? Am I correct?

In theory, yes it's the same to iterate an array from the end and from the start.
The time complexity is O(10,000) which is constant so O(1) assuming that the loop body has a constant time complexity. But it's nice to mention that the constant 10,000 can be promoted to a variable, call it `N`, and then you can say that the time complexity is O(N).

> Also I was asked regarding ArrayList Complexity compared to other collections in java, for example, LinkedList.

Here you can find comparison between ArrayList and LinkedList time complexity. The interesting methods are `add`, `remove` and `get`.
http://www.programcreek.com/2013/03/arraylist-vs-linkedlist-vs-vector/

Also, data in a LinkedList are not stored consuecutively. However, data in an ArrayList are stored consecutively and also an ArrayList uses less space than a LinkedList
Good luck!